# dllimport a c++ method to c#. When calling from C#, the programm gets closed without any error message

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dllimport

I want to compile a c++ program to a dll and use it from c#.

This is the c++ program:

[MurmurHash3.h](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/branches/chandlerc_dev/MurmurHash3.h) [MurmurHash3.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/branches/chandlerc_dev/MurmurHash3.cpp)

I changed the header and the method declaration in the h and c++ file from:

```
void MurmurHash3_x64_128 ( const void * key, int len, uint32_t seed, void * out );
```

to

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void MurmurHash3_x64_128 
    (const void * key, const int len, const uint32_t seed, void * out )
```

I did the same for all three methods. Then I set the compile target to dll. After compiling it I had a x64 bit dll named SMHasher.dll. Now I created a new x64 bit C# programm and used this dll as reference.

Then I wrote the following:

```
[DllImport("SMHasher.dll")]
public static extern void MurmurHash3_x64_128(byte[] valueToHash, int len, uint seed, out byte[] hash);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] hash;
    MurmurHash3_x64_128(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3, 0, out hash);
}
```

When calling MurmurHash3_x64_128 my test app gets closed without any error message.

What is the problem? And how can I solve it?

Maybe the problems are the c++ parameters? Maybe "const void * key" is not a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because you are a 64-bit app importing a 32-bit dll, or a 32-bit app importing a 64-bit dll.

Make sure you LoadLibrary a dll of the same bittedness of your app.

In C#, you can set the bittedness of your app through the use of the configuration properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: I already compiled the dll as 64 bit, but not my c# app. Now I also used 64bit here. Now my c# program just closes without any errors when I reach the dll call.

Comment: Try stepping through your function to see what happens. If necessary add a debug-breakpoint in your C++ application to check that your function is being reached, and you should be able to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: It is an other solution, so I can not debug it. But the problem is solved now. I had to marshal the out and key params. Thank you for your initial 64bit help. It solved my first question, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful about the calling conventions.

In c/c++, cdecl is the default. But in [DllImport] of C#, it's stdcall.

Try define your c++ function like this:

```
void __stdcall MurmurHash3_x64_128 ( const void * key, int len, uint32_t seed, void * out );
```

And you'd better use a .def file to make sure the function name is not changed.

And one more thing, you didn't allocate memory for your `byte[] hash;` maybe it causes stack corruption...

Comment: When changing the function definition and calling it from c#, I get the error "EntryPointNotFoundException". I set the value hash to "byte[] hash = new byte[16];". I don't know how I get the .def file. While compiling the c++ project, there is none.

Comment: I have written a test c++ method I can call. The problem are these two parameters: "const void * key" and "void * out"

Comment: @Chris The reason your c# code get 'EntryPointNotFoundException' is the linker renamed your function. Create a .DEF in your project to prevent the linker from renaming your function. You can google for how to write the .DEF file.